# trying to generate a d.ts file for a .js file and I am getting a billion errors

Tags: typescript

I have a .js file.. I am doing:
`npx -p typescript tsc ./my_file.js  --declaration --allowJs --emitDeclarationOnly --outDir .`

And I get billions of errors like:

```
  node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3209:13
    3209             "var": React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>;
                     ~~~~~
    '"var"' was also declared here.

../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:2942:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'video' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<VideoHTMLAttributes<HTMLVideoElement>, HTMLVideoElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<VideoHTMLAttributes<HTMLVideoElement>, HTMLVideoElement>'.

2942             video: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.VideoHTMLAttributes<HTMLVideoElement>, HTMLVideoElement>;
                 ~~~~~
```

Why is it going into node modules and looking at files that I have not specified?!